# What does "code and ABI that are needed by web3" refer to in solc / nodejs

Tags: solidity, web3js, nodejs

```
var input = "contract x { function g() {} }";
var output = solc.compile(input, 1); // 1 activates the optimiser
for (var contractName in output.contracts) {
    // code and ABI that are needed by web3
    console.log(contractName + ': ' + output.contracts[contractName].bytecode);
    console.log(contractName + '; ' + JSON.parse( output.contracts[contractName].interface));
}
```

Everything is working out, but when I get lost the last part, I'm unsure of what values to input in the first parentheses, and the `//code and ABI that are needed by web3`. Can you please help?

```
for (var contractName in output.contracts) {
    // code and ABI that are needed by web3
    console.log(contractName + ': ' + output.contracts[contractName].bytecode);
    console.log(contractName + '; ' + JSON.parse( output.contracts[contractName].interface));
}
```

Comment: "unsure of what values to input in the first parentheses"  Hi, what's the question, which parentheses?  If talking about `for (var contractName in output.contracts)`  there is nothing to change there.  The comment `//` is also just a comment, no need to write any code there.

Answer (score 6):

## Source Code, Bytecode and Application Binary Interface

If you plug your source code `contract x { function g() {} }` into the left hand pane of the [Solidity Online Compiler](http://chriseth.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-latest.js), you will see on the right hand side a **Bytecode** text box which contains the binary representation of your source code. This is what `output.contracts[contractName].bytecode` will contain, and from the online compiler is:

```
606060405260478060106000396000f360606040526000357c010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000090048063e2179b8e146037576035565b005b604260048050506044565b005b5b56
```

You will also find an **Interface** text box on the right hand side containing the **Application Binary Interface**. This is what `output.contracts[contractName].interface` will contain, and from the online compiler this is:

```
[{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"g","outputs":[],"type":"function"}]
```

## Compilation of Source Code

The following statement assigns your contract source to the variable `input`:

```
var input = "contract x { function g() {} }";
```

The following statement calls the Solidity compiler to compile your source code and store the resulting information into the variable `output`:

```
var output = solc.compile(input, 1); // 1 activates the optimiser
```

## Other Information

I was searching for a bit more information on Solidity and node.js, and found your example from [chriseth/browser-solidity](https://github.com/chriseth/browser-solidity)
. Remember to install your Solidity compiler for use by node.js using the statement:

```
npm install solc
```

Answer (score 0):

Took me a little while to figure this one out and @BokkyPooBah's answer certainly helped. However here is some code that works for me right now.

```
var contract = output.contracts[':' + myContractName];
var abi = JSON.parse(contract.interface);
var code = '0x' + contract.bytecode;
```

Note that:

- The contract name will be prefixed with `:` in the `contracts` hash (this doesn't matter if looping through property names as in the example, but is a pain when you're interested in a particular contract)
- The `interface` returned in the compiled contract is a JSON string and not an array as required by web3.
- The `bytecode` field is missing the `0x` hex prefix that is required by web3.

**Bonus note: I found the solc-js compiler orders of magnitude slower than using the binary compiler through web3 and a running node so I'm not sure I would recommend using it. In fact I think I would recommend just using the `solc` binary directly.**